# Adding the I-CUBE-LRWAN library to a STM32CubeMX project

Tags: embedded, stm32, gsm, gateway, lora

My team and I are currently working on a project that involve a ST board (the  STM32L072CZYxx) to create a bidirectionnal GSM-LoRa gateway.

As we've already succeeded in implementing the GSM side of the gateway, we are currently working on the LoRa part of the project. To achieve this, we're trying to use the [I-CUBE-LRWAN](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/i-cube-lrwan.html), but can't figure out how to add this library to the [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) project. It seems like, this library can't be added to our project through STM32CubeMX. The only solution we have is to add manually the library to the project but we can't figure out how to do it. We imported the middlewares we needed into the project however, the IDE we use (Atollic TRUEStudio or SW4STM32) detects a lot of errors in the project and we really don't understand why (the source for middlewares were coded by ST, so basically no errors).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that is Murata LoRa Module. First time I tried that I was not able to add library to existing project.

There is some error that occur because of length of path names -on windows- you can copy and paste the project to shorten the path name and then i was able to program the module to use it as AT command slave.

And also there is 3 target project on that project file you need to select the proper target for it.